# Repair A Blacktop Asphalt Driveway or hire a pro?

Tags: driveway, diy-vs-pro, asphalt

I have an asphalt driveway.

I have:

> two 1/8" deep indents (from car tires)
>
> separation from the garage floor
>
> a big spider crack in the center
>
> dull/worn look

How do I DIY repair?  Or is this better left to a pro?

[image: indents]

[image: gap]

[image: crack]

Comment: 1. more hotmix and a roller will patch that, though it's likely the base is too think and you'll need to repeat periodically. 2. tar up those seems. 3. tar up the cracks. dull: use an asphalt resurfacer. pro: not unless you really want it in "mint" condition.

Comment: Answers go down there, Dan.